# C++ Fibonacci Program

Tags: c++, fibonacci

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting one number in the sequence in advance? I can't seem to find what's wrong! 
For example, If you type in 10, you should get 34, but get 55 (one number ahead, i.e 11)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fibonacci (int n);

int main ()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Fibonacci number generator" << endl;
    cout << "Which one do you want (0 to exist)?";
    cin >> n;
    cout << fibonacci(n);
}


int fibonacci (int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return (fibonacci(n - 2) + (fibonacci(n - 1)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code, so that it's readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define your first number.

In your code, it looks like it starts from 1, so there's nothing wrong to output 55 for the 10th element.

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55
```

However, I think you were accidentally making it right, and I am guessing that what you're trying to do is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int fibonacci (int n);

int main () {
    int n;
    cout<<"Fibonacci number generator"<<endl;
    cout<<"Which one do you want (0 to exist)?";

    cin>>n;
    if(n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    cout<<fibonacci(n);

    return 0;
}

int fibonacci (int n) {
    if (n == 1){
        return 0;
    } else if (n == 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return (fibonacci(n-2)+(fibonacci(n-1)));
    }
}
```

That is,

- exit when input is 0
- the sequence is like this: `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 21, 34`

Comment: +1. I agree with this answer. But just to annoy you, well, I think it "starts" from the zeroth element of value 0...

Answer (score 0):

The Fibonacci number sequence used to be:

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55
```

but in modern times it has morphed to:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55
```

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number.

If you use the first sequence, the seeds are defined as:

```
F(1) = 1
F(2) = 1
```

If you use the second sequence, the seeds are defined as:

```
F(0) = 0
F(1) = 1
```

As long as we all agree that `F(10)` is `55`, it does not matter whether it's the 10-th number in the (first) sequence or the 11-th number in the (second) sequence.